# Automatic TypeScript `import` formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, path, visual-studio-code, quotes

I'm working on an Angular 9 project in Visual Studio Code. When I type the name of an existing TypeScript class, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to import it automatically. How can I configure the auto-import functionality to use double quotes and relative paths instead of single quotes and absolute paths?

Example:

- I get this: `import { RefreshService } from 'src/app/services/refresh.service';`
- I want this: `import { RefreshService } from "../../services/refresh.service";`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPen visual studio and open `File -> preferences->settings`  and **search auto import** [image: see image] select extension TypeScript and change drop down option(Quote style) auto to double.

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines had to be added to `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double"
```